# How to preserve shell variables in script after changing user

Tags: linux, shell, sudo, users, variable

How can I access same variables data after switching users? For example:

```
artifact=archive.tar.gz
workdir=/home/user

echo "$workdir/$artifact"
sudo -u otheruser bash
echo "$workdir/$artifact"
```

Produces:

```
/home/user/archive.tar.gz
/
```

Is it possible that second `echo` would resolve in same path as the first one?

Edit:
Complete solution, thanks to @Romeo Ninov and @steeldriver:

```
export artifact=archive.tar.gz
export workdir=/home/user

echo "$workdir/$artifact"
sudo -Eu otheruser bash
echo "$workdir/$artifact"
```

Comment: The `sudo` in your script would start a new shell. The remainder of the script would run as the original user once that shell exits. There is no way to "switch users" in the middle of a shell script.

Comment: See also [Why can't we execute a list of commands as different user without sudo?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/86778)

Comment: As is, you should get the proper variable twice, `sudo -u otheruser bash` will fork a new bash without wanted values, but when you exit, `"$workdir/$artifact"` should be the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Export the variables:

```
export artifact=archive.tar.gz
export workdir=/home/user
```

Comment: Whether that works or not will depend on the sudoers `env_reset` / `env_keep` policy I think - and may require addition of `-E` (or `--preserve-env`)?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use `zsh` instead of `bash` which has support for changing uids and gids (provided it is started with super-user privileges):

```
#! /bin/zsh -
id
echo "Original user: $SUDO_USER"
var=test
(
  USERNAME=$SUDO_USER
  echo "Runing as $(id -un) in this subshell var=$var"
)
(USERNAME=nobody; echo and now:; id; echo $var)
```

Running as:

```
$ sudo ./that-script
uid=0(root) gid=0(root) groups=0(root)
Original user: stephane
Runing as stephane in this subshell var=test
and now:
uid=65534(nobody) gid=65534(nogroup) groups=65534(nogroup)
test
```

Setting `USERNAME` sets the uid, euid, gid, egid and supplimentary gids as if logging in or using `sudo`. You can also set the `UID`/`EUID`/`GID`... variables individually.